# Problemas ao atualizar MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estou com um problema que depois que atualizei o MAMP para a versão 5.7.25 do mysql , ao tentar inserir um registro ele simplesmente pede no tipo correto, exemplo: tenho um campo ID onde é inteiro e auto-incremento, então na inserção, não coloco, mas aí o mysql exigi e que venha preenchido com um inteiro, alguém já passou por isso? sabe como resolver? agradeço a todos que poderem me ajudar.

Comment: qual o erro que retorna?